# Sonarqube adding tags to rules

Tags: database, tags, sonarqube

firstly, we have a custom profile with rules from different sources. We want to add some tags to these rules in order to classify them according to our requirements.

We are adding our tags directly into the database with SQL, in the table rule_metadata but the problem is that in the sonarqube interface our new tags works fine when we scan a project (the new tags works in the issues tab) but when we see the rules tab we can not filter the rules or find our tags.

Any idea of how can we add tags to the rules in this way and make the sonar interface works with them? we try restarting sonar, making new projects etc.

Comment: In general it is not a good idea to update the database directly. Why not use the WEB API?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Well, the WEP API have some restrictions, we need to add different tags to all the rules from built-in plugin and also external.

Answer (score 0):

The database is not an API, you should never directly insert data in it.
You should use UI or Web service to interact with SonarQube.

As a consequence of updating the DB, there's no warranty of what can happen...